# Session Some Time reurn Null And some time reurn value

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, session

I create session when user Login and use session to check access page, when i check session some time rerun null if i refresh page or navigate to other page the session is not null , it's not about specific page ,it's about method some time return null some time get session value , my method in web service and i call it use javascript

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]            
    public object CheckIfLoggedin()
    {
        try
        {
            return new { Result = resultEnum.ok, Records = GetUserID() };

        }
        catch
        {
            return new { Result = resultEnum.error };
        }

    }
    private Guid? GetUserID()
    {
        if (Context.Session["User"] != null)
        {
            string userid = Context.Session["User"].ToString();
            if (userid != "")
                return new Guid(userid);
            else
                return null;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    function CheckIfLoggedin() {

    var status = 0;

    var ItemCount;
    $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "../../../../_layouts/15/TripPlannerFrontend/TripPlannerSrv.asmx/CheckIfLoggedin",

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (res) {
        if (res.d.Result === 2) {
            var userid = res.d.Records;
            if (userid == null) {
                //
            }
            else {

                //window.location = "TripPlanner.aspx";
                var returnurl = GetQueryString("returnurl");
                if (returnurl != null && returnurl !== "")
                    window.location = returnurl;
                else
                    window.location = "TripPlanner.aspx";
            } 

        }
        else
            console.log("try again");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log("try again");
    }
});
   };
```

Comment: Don't you have multiple Web front-end servers with load-balancing and no session-affinity?

Comment: i have multiple Web front-end servers with load-balancing i do not think there is any session-affinity  , do i need session-affinity ?

Comment: Context.Session  , Session  current.Session what is the different ? which one should i use use in Webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer to my question in the comments, I think your problem is session affinity. If you have multiple Web front-ends in your SharePoint farm, and a load-balancer dispatching requests to one of these SP servers: a first request may be routed to server A, then the session is created, and when a second request is issued by the client, it may be redirected to server B, where the session does not exist.

In such situations, the **best** approach is to configure your load-balancer for "session affinity": this means that once a given client is assigned one of the Web front-ends, all subsequent requests will be redirected to the same server. Ask the Administrator of the load-balancer if this can be configured at his level (it depends on the technology used for load-balancing).

Another approach is to configure session at the servers level to be stored in a SQL database. See for instance http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/asp-net-session-state-implementation-in-sharepoint for more info on this.

Comment: thank you i will try this, but the link is not correct

Comment: The link should be OK now. It was http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/asp-net-session-state-implementation-in-sharepoint with 'sharepoint' all lower-case, while the autocorrect had changed it to 'SharePoint'... and apparently the server at sharepoint-community.net process case-sensitive URLs! Crazy.